# NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment.movie_id djnago

Tags: python, django

I get the error NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment.movie_id
. I'm trying to return the average of comments and ratings in a model Class Movie, but I get the error NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment.movie_id
. How can I fix it?

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    
    def get_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=self.id)
    
    def average_stars(self):
        comments = self.get_comments()
        n_comments = comments.count()
        if n_comments == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return sum([comment.stars for comment in comments]) / n_comments
    

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    stars       = models.FloatField(
                     blank=False,
                     null=False,
                     default=0, 
                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator(10.0)]
                  )

    user        = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    movie       = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```
def view_movie_detail(request, movie_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user  
        comment = request.POST.get("comment")
        stars = request.POST.get("stars")
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = User.objects.get(id=1)

        Comment(comment=comment, stars = stars, user=user,movie_id=movie_id).save()

        return redirect(f"/movie/{movie_id}/")
    else:
        data = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        recommendations = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        comments = reversed(Movie().get_comments())
        average = Movie().average_stars()
        return render(request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", {
            "data": data.json(),
            "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
            "type": "movie",
            "comments": comments,
            "average" : average,
        })
```

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment.movie_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

trace back:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\81804\enviroment\MovieReview\MovieReview\Movies\views.py", line 74, in view_movie_detail
Comment(comment=comment, stars = stars, user=user,movie_id=movie_id).save()
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
self.save_base(
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert(
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
return manager._insert(
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1434, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1632, in execute_sql
self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_columns(
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 205, in fetch_returned_insert_columns
return cursor.fetchone()
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\81804\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /movie/616037/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Comment: Adding the error trace show the exact location of the error and help potential answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide traceback, the only place that may cause such error is here:

```
Comment(comment=comment, stars = stars, user=user,movie_id=movie_id).save()
```

You are creating new object, but your variable `movie_id` seems empty (`None`). You need to make sure it's passed in the right way to the view like `http://yourdomain.com/view_movie_detail/12/`.

Comment: And it says exactly what I wrote:
`"C:\Users\81804\enviroment\MovieReview\MovieReview\Movies\views.py", line 74, in view_movie_detail Comment(comment=comment, stars = stars, user=user,movie_id=movie_id).save() File`. Look there.